# Trying to find any AMI's created in the last hour

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We build new AMI's frequently for deployments. I'm trying to write something that will do a return a list of any AMI's our account has created in the last hour. Reasoning for this is we can't kick off the deployments until we're sure all the AMI's are created.

I have a function to find AMI's, just stuck on figuring out how to narrow the search to only AMI's created in the last 60 minutes. What I'm working with is from another lambda I created to find any AMI's created in the last 30 days. It doesn't scale down to hours that I can tell, which is where I could use some help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import datetime

age = 1
aws_profile_name = 'default'

current_images = []

# Functions to calculate age for AMI's and Snapshots. 
def ami_days_old(date):
    lastHourDateTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
    return lastHourDateTime

# Setup boto3 client connections
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name = aws_profile_name)
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

# Filter on what to search for in order to grab just OUR images and snapshots
custom_filter = [{
    'Name':'<redacted>', 
    'Values': ['<redacted>']}]

def get_recent_images():
    amis = ec2.describe_images(Owners=['self'], Filters=custom_filter)
    for ami in amis['Images']:
        create_date = ami['CreationDate']
        location = ami['ImageLocation']
        ami_id = ami['ImageId']
        # print ami['ImageId'], ami['CreationDate']
        day_old = ami_days_old(create_date)
        if day_old > age:
            try:

                print("deleting -> " + ami_id + " - create_date = " + create_date + " as image is " + str(day_old)  + " old.")
                # deregister the AMI
                #ec2.deregister_image(ImageId=ami_id)
            except:
                print("can't delete " + ami_id)

def main():
    get_recent_images()
    print(get_recent_images())

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```py
def ami_days_old(date):
    lastHourDateTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
    return lastHourDateTime
```

is being passed a `date` parameter, but your code is not using it! Instead, it is returning a timestamp from 1 hour ago, but your code is expecting an age??

```
age = 1
...
        create_date = ami['CreationDate']
        ...
        if day_old > age:
```

So, your code is all mixed up!

Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
...

  if ami['CreationDate'] > datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=1):
```